# copy lines from a text file to another

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have two text files

file1 has the following lines

```
line1
line2
hello-hai-1
hello-2-hai
3-hai-hello
hello
```

and file 2 has

```
line4
line3
hello-hai-5
hello-7-hai
6-hai-hello
hai
hello-4
```

what i want to do is copy all the lines which contain both hello and hai in file2 and overwrite it on those lines in file1, the no. of lines may or may not be equal. but all the hello-hai lines are together in both files

the current code i use is

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('^<file2 essentials\findstr.exe /n "hello"') do set "#%%i=%%j"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (file1) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    if not "!line!"=="!line:hello=!" (
    if not "!line!"=="!line:hai=!" (
        if not defined flag (
            for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set "#"') do echo(%%b
            set "flag=true"
        )
        ) else echo !line!
    )  else echo(!line!
))>output.txt
```

this copies all hello lines over the hello-hai lines in file1, i want to know how to add the word hai to the search in first file

Comment: You have got two [accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2349863/mohammed-akzin-k)?

Comment: nope that was my brother, i was in my native place, and i asked him to post it for me

Comment: Excuse me, I think your code doesn't work. It copies _all matching lines_ from file2 in the place of _the first_ matching line of file1. From that point on, it just deletes matching lines from file1. **EDIT**: My mistake! I re-read your question and I realize that all lines are together! I apologize... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Find lines with both strings in file2
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "hello" file2 ^| findstr "hai"') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "file2[!i!]=%%a"
)

rem Merge file1 with the found lines in file2
set i=0
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:hello=!" neq "!line!" (
      if "!line:hai=!" neq "!line!" (
         set /A i+=1
         for %%i in (!i!) do echo !file2[%%i]!
      ) else (
         echo !line!
      )
   ) else (
      echo !line!
   )
)) > output.txt
```

**EDIT**: *New version added*

Previous solution achieve a line-by-line replacement that works even if the matching lines are not together in any file (*file merge*), but requires that the number of matching lines be the same in both files. The new simpler version below works  in the way requested by the OP:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:hello=!" neq "!line!" (
      if "!line:hai=!" neq "!line!" (
         if not defined flag (
            findstr "hello" file2 | findstr "hai"
            set flag=true
         )
      ) else (
         echo !line!
      )
   ) else (
      echo !line!
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Comment: but you forgot `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in the second version.

Comment: now i have a problem, this changes the EOL, character from unix to windows, any way i can keep it as unix itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "tf1=%temp%\~%random%1"
set "tf2=%temp%\~%random%2"
set "tf3=%temp%\~%random%3"
set "tf4=%temp%\~%random%4"
set "pt=hello"
set "pu=hai"
<file1 findstr /lin "%pt%">"%tf1%"
<"%tf1%" findstr /li "%pu%">"%tf2%"
<file2 findstr /li "%pt%">"%tf3%"
<"%tf3%" findstr /li "%pu%">"%tf4%"
for /f "usebackqdelims=:" %%i in ("%tf2%") do (
    if not defined st set "st=%%i"
    set "fi=%%i"
)
set /a st-=1
<file1 (
for /l %%i in (1,1,%st%) do (
    set "line="
    set/p "line="
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%tf1%"
<file1>"%tf3%" more +%fi%
copy /a "%tf1%"+"%tf4%"+"%tf3%"=output.txt>nul
del "%temp%\~*"
type output.txt
```

output is:

```
line1
line2
hello-hai-5
hello-7-hai
6-hai-hello
hello
```

Comment: could you expalin a bit more after the `for /f "usebackqdelims=:` line?

Comment: `for /f "usebackqdelims=:" %%i in ("%tf2%") do` this command reads the second temp file from file1 with both "hello" and "hai" containing lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET searching=Y
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file1.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%i|FIND "hello"|FIND "hai" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%i) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED searching TYPE "file2.txt"|FIND "hello"|FIND "hai"
  SET "searching="
 )
)
)>output.txt
TYPE output.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a version without tempfiles. It simply reproduces lines from file1 that don't contain BOTH of the target strings. When BOTH are found in the same line, it outputs all of those lines in file2 that contain both strings. The `searching` flag is used to ensure that the file2 lines are only output once.

It won't reproduce blank lines or lines that begin `;`. Could be made to do so if required.

Comment: Nice, but I think, even in large files it is a time consuming process to send each line through two pipes. Each pipe needs a own `cmd` on both sides.

Comment: tried this and it said the syntax of the command is incorrect, the file gets written though.